# Cumulative sum over a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, cumulative-sum

What is the best way to perform a cumulative sum over a table in Postgres, in a way that can bring the best performance and flexibility in case more fields / columns are added to the table.

**Table**

```
    a   b   d
1   59  15  181
2       16  268
3           219
4           102
```

**Cumulative**

```
    a   b   d
1   59  15  181
2       31  449
3           668
4           770
```

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  You need a column to specify the ordering.  I assume the first column of numbers represents this value in the data.

Comment: I think your example should include the case, where a row has values *after* a previous rows had NULL values. What should the result look like in this case?

Comment: Yes Erwin, thanks! your and the other answers were helpful! I was searching for a way to get sums per group of values! Not that hard after all :)

Answer (score 3):

Window functions for running sum.

```
SELECT sum(a) OVER (ORDER BY d) as "a",
       sum(b) OVER (ORDER BY d) as "b",
       sum(d) OVER (ORDER BY d) as "d" 
FROM table;
```

If you have more than one running sum, make sure the orders are the same.

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html
- http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/119-Running-totals-and-sums-using-PostgreSQL-8.4-Windowing-functions.html

---

It's important to note that if you want your columns to appear as the aggregate table in your question (each field uniquely ordered), it'd be a little more involved.

---

Update: I've modified the query to do the required sorting, without a given common field.

### SQL Fiddle: [(1) Only Aggregates](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/5b041/43), or [(2) Source Data Beside Running Sum](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/5b041/57)

```
WITH 
rcd AS ( 
  select row_number() OVER() as num,a,b,d 
  from tbl
),
sorted_a AS (
  select row_number() OVER(w1) as num, sum(a) over(w2) a
  from tbl
  window w1 as (order by a nulls last),
         w2 as (order by a nulls first)
),
sorted_b AS (
  select row_number() OVER(w1) as num, sum(b) over(w2) b
  from tbl
  window w1 as (order by b nulls last),
         w2 as (order by b nulls first)
),
sorted_d AS (
  select row_number() OVER(w1) as num, sum(d) over(w2) d
  from tbl
  window w1 as (order by d nulls last),
         w2 as (order by d nulls first)
)

SELECT sorted_a.a, sorted_b.b, sorted_d.d 
FROM rcd 
JOIN sorted_a USING(num)
JOIN sorted_b USING(num)
JOIN sorted_d USING(num)
ORDER BY num;
```

Comment: Hi vol7ron, Yes, that works, although there is one problem. first I forgot to give a name to the first (index) column, let's say it is called 'I'. I believe in your example, the window func will use `...(ORDER BY I)`. Still, this does not output the **cumulative** table in the format above, where there are 'empty' cells. your solution will output something like <pre>60;15;181
60;31;451
60;31;670
60;31;784
</pre>

Comment: @Algina I've updated the answer.  It's not as compact as Gordon's, or my original, but it will handle the sorting and no `id` field is necessary.  If the source data is already pre-sorted, go with Gordon's; otherwise, you'd need to do individual field sorts and then join them together, like the above edit.

Comment: Cool, that works also and is cool to see another approach. Very nice! thanks

Comment: This has the benefit of handling mid-row breaks. I've updated to show how easy it would be to also show the source data next to the total columns.

Answer (score 3):

You can use window functions, but you need additional logic to avoid values where there are `NULL`s:

```
SELECT id,
       (case when a is not null then sum(a) OVER (ORDER BY id) end) as a,
       (case when b is not null then sum(b) OVER (ORDER BY id) end) as b,
       (case when d is not null then sum(d) OVER (ORDER BY id) end) as d 
FROM table;
```

This assumes that the first column that specifies the ordering is called `id`.

Comment: Don't NULLs have no affect in summation?

Comment: Perfect Gordon! Thanks

Comment: Yep http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ac0af/3/0 , @vol7ron I believe he did that to avoid repeating the running total downward. Ie. otherwise 59 in column A would be repeated 3 times. The desired result shows it only once.

Comment: Correct @BrianDeMilia! Thanks also for the example.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, this would mean that your data would also need to be  pre-sorted, right?  If `d` had a `NULL` somewhere in the middle rows, I'm guessing there would be a break in the records, then the summations would continue on the following record — does that sound right?

Comment: @vol7ron, yes that is correct! in case of some `NULL` in the middle , a break will exist. Any idea of a simple way to solve this, without affecting cells where no data exists. for instance, in the first **table** of my example, in case cell values *219* ->*(celll:3b)* is not present, **cumulative** table will then show exactlly the same, with the difference of *cell 3d* that will show *449 * and *cell 4d* that will show *551 *.

Comment: @Algina . . . I would suggest that you ask another question about the `NULL`s in the middle.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Algina: The bottom of my answer would solve the break concern, but it's quadrupling the query, so take that with a grain of salt (may or may not be a performance hit given your dataset). Instead of having the *database* do this, it might be better to handle it at the *application layer*.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are really looking for is this:

```
SELECT id
     , sum(a) OVER (PARTITION BY a_grp ORDER BY id) as a
     , sum(b) OVER (PARTITION BY b_grp ORDER BY id) as b
     , sum(d) OVER (PARTITION BY d_grp ORDER BY id) as d 
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , count(a IS NULL OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY id) as a_grp
        , count(b IS NULL OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY id) as b_grp
        , count(d IS NULL OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY id) as d_grp
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
ORDER  BY id;
```

The expression  `count(col IS NULL OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY id)` forms groups of consecutive non-null rows for `a`, `b` and `d` in the subquery `sub`.

In the outer query we run cumulative sums *per group*. `NULL` values form their own group and stay `NULL` automatically. No additional `CASE` statement necessary.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53c1c/1) (with some added values for column `a` to demonstrate the effect).

Comment: I may be missing something — in the fiddle, column A isn't sorted and doesn't have a cumulative sum

Comment: @vol7ron: The fiddle hat two queries, the first was yours to compare to, the second mine. I simplified now to only show my query.

Comment: yes, but when I looked at your table, column "A" was not reporting the right values (and still is not)

Comment: @vol7ron: The values for `A` are correct in both fiddles AFAIUI. I think that's what the OP is really looking for: running sums per group of values.

Comment: I see, so in a column, running sums stop at breaks (NULLs) and start again when a new non-NULL is encountered, instead of resuming from where it left off earlier.

Comment: @vol7ron: Exactly. This doesn't become clear from the question, but reading the OP's comments I think that's what he's after.

Comment: Totally agreed.  I just re-read the comment in Gordon's answer.  I think he was describing taking away d3 (`219`) and replacing it with a NULL value.  In place of the NULL, it would be another `449` (like d2), counting the NULL as a `0` and continue to do this until the next encountered integer; however instead of starting a new sum, he would resume the cumulative total (what he meant by `551`, instead of saying `102`).  I could be mistaken, but think Gordon was right in suggesting a new question, or revising the current.

Comment: Just upvoted your answer, for the detective work to find out the *question* alone. ;)

Comment: Haha I wish I could favorite answers because yours has more use with exporting to Excel; especially breaking data into groups. Of course, I think the question is asking for something that relational databases *can*, but *shouldn't* be doing